# Is it OK to have 39 font files?

Tags: fonts, frontend, webfonts

So I've downloaded fonts (Comfortaa, Cormorant Garamond, Cormorant Unicase and Old Standart TT) from Google Fonts and converted them into Webfonts using Transfonter, the output is 39 font files (13 font files of each format WOFF, WOFF2, TTF). Google Fonts says that load time with these fonts included is "Moderate". I wonder what does that mean? Is it OK for a small business website? Does converting into Webfont impact performance in any way? Am I doing it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When using fonts, I recommend using a CDN as they can reach high file sizes. The meaning of the "load time" is the time it takes a typical user to download the font from your website. When using font's from *Google Fonts* use their provided Embed, they provide a free CDN around the globe so you can have adequate load times for everyone.

The scale of your business is irrelevant, the only thing that matters on how you deliver the files; in your case, it will be Google's CDN.

Comment: Google's CDN vs Webfonts on my hosting, what would be superior in terms of performance? Can I anyhow lower "load time"?

Comment: Google's CDN would be far superior if you're using a conventional hosting provider. The only way to "lower load time" would be to reduce the number of fonts you use.